# AVAudioPlayer Play in background

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, background-process

As per our requirement we need to play sound even if the app is in background. We are using `[AVAudioPlayer Play]` for the  purpose of playing sound.

It works if the application is in foreground. But if application is in background and we are playing song in music player as well and then control goes to `[AVAudioPlayer Play]` statement, nothing happens.

We have already gone through many links, added the background modes in plist and have also added  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];` but things did not work out.

Please suggest if there are any other alternatives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVAudioPlayer play file in Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965419/avaudioplayer-play-file-in-background)

Answer (score 11):

Just add these three lines where you initialize the `AVAudioPlayer`'s instance:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySong" ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

// These lines need to be added:

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 3):

To play your audio in background just add in your **info.plist**make an array like this[image]

and check it into real device not in simulator

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = 0;
    task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```